# How to use createCipheriv() method in react-native-crypto? I want to create the secret password in my app

Tags: javascript, react-native

Could someone please help me with how to use react-native-crypto?

I was previously using react-native-rncryptor to generate a secret password from the user's password and the 'secret' string. However, when I tried building the APK file, this module stopped working.

```
 const encryptedPassword = await RNCryptor.encrypt(
        userCredential.password,
        'secret'
      );
```

Now, I am considering using the react-native-crypto module instead. However, I am unsure which function to use and how to use it. I attempted using createCipheriv(), but it did not work.

I would appreciate any assistance in understanding how to utilize react-native-crypto and which function would be suitable for my use case.

```
  public void encrypt(String text, String password, Promise promise) {
    JNCryptor cryptor = new AES256JNCryptor();
    byte[] plaintext = text.getBytes();

    try {
      byte[] ciphertext = cryptor.encryptData(plaintext, password.toCharArray());
      String base64 = Base64.encodeToString(ciphertext, Base64.DEFAULT);
      promise.resolve(base64);
    } catch (CryptorException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
      promise.reject(e);
    }
  }
```

This is the code block what I used in the issue app.

```
import RNCryptor from 'react-native-rncryptor';
     const encryptedPassword = await RNCryptor.encrypt(
        userCredential.password,
        'secret'
      );
```